# Can't connect to SQL Server local database and can't find the SQL Server browser

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, ssms

My problem is that after I installed SQL Server Management Studio and use `.\SQLEXPRESS` as a server name. It says that it can't connect it.

I read lots of things about that problem and one thing was to go to computer management and check the sql server browser if it is started.

When I go there I do not find any files for sql. On time of the installing I do everything correct as it is supposed to be. That's why I cannot understand why it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Goto Control Panel --> Administrator Tools --> Services select SQL SERVER (MSSQLSERVER) and double click on it

Comment: The problem is that SQL SERVER ( MSSQLSERVER) is missing.

Comment: When I go to Services I can't find anything about SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have installed the tools only (SQL Management Studio) and not SQL Server itself.  If you want to connect to your own SQL Server (any instance starting with a dot ".") then you will need to install it on your machine.

You can download the full installation SQL Express package direct from Microsoft. There are several editions available to suit your environment and needs.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

It gets a little complicated trying to find what you want since there are so many variants and editions. I recommend that you head over to Scott Hanselman's blog where he has laid it all out very nicely by release version, edition and environment (32/64 bit)

His preferred link: http://downloadsqlserverexpress.com

Original post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx

Comment: You saved my life. It worked. I was installing just the SQL Management Studio but not the whole SQL Server EXPRESS. Thank you !

Comment: Ha, for me it was because I thought "Oh, I don't need replication", but then proceeded to uncheck Database Engine Services...

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems it isnt installed... was it installed? Check google what it's folders are for your system and go look if the folders exist. Make a backup of existing folders and re-install if need be. then attach any existing files to to recreate the databases, if any.

Comment: It's odd that a guy answers the question, tells you you that you need to install the software and then someone else answers the same thing but with links you could get from google and all of a sudden his answer was wrong...